# How do I pull attributes from deeply nested XML sub elements using ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, parsing, elementtree

I have .xml files that i am attempting to pull attributes from, and i am having trouble grabbing the attributes from the Raw_Material Sub element. Below is some sample data that represents what the files look like:

```xml
    <XML_Order order_Id='1' terms='Net30' ship_via='UPS'>
        <Line_Items>
            <Line_Item upc='1234567' item_id='1' color='blk' qty='15'>
                <Raw_Materials>
                    <Raw_Material Item_Id='H188' Vendor_Id='DI0001'> # This is what i need to grab
                    <Raw_Material Item_Id='ST03' Vendor_Id='DI0001'>
                </Raw_Materials>
            </Line_Item>
            <Line_Item>
                <Raw_Materials>
                    <Raw_Material>
                    <Raw_Material>
                </Raw_Materials>
            </Line_Item>
            <Line_Item>
                <Raw_Materials>
                    <Raw_Material>
                    <Raw_Material>
                </Raw_Materials>
            </Line_Item>
        </Line_Items>
    </XML_Order>
```

I am having no problem iterating and pulling the attributes from the Line_Item tags using the following code:

```py
    if filename.endswith('.xml'):
        tree = Et.ElementTree(file = filename)
        root = tree.getroot()
    # order info
    orderID = root.attrib['Order_Id']    # grab order ID from XML document
    terms = root.attrib['terms']
    shipVia = root.attrib['ship_via']

    for child in root:
        for grandchild in child:
            upc = grandchild.get('upc')
            lineItemID = grandchild.get('item_Id')
            color = grandchild.get('item_Id')

            # I assume this is where i would need a for loop to access the
            # nested <Raw_Material> element and its attributes
```

I attempted to fill a list with the values with the following in my code (where the last comment is):

```py
    for element in tree.iter(tag = 'Raw_Material'):
        itemID.append(element.get('Item_Id'))
```

and python returns the itemID list with the correct itemId's, but they are repeated over and over, when I only need it to grab the 2 item_Id attribute values. I think it is appending the list for each line item tag in my xml doc, instead of a new list for line item tag

Once I grab the data i need, would a list be the best way to hold the values? There will only ever be be 1 or 2 Raw_Material sub elements, and i don't want my variables to overwrite in a loop.

Comment: After playing around with the code some more, it seems that i can grab the Item_Id attribute value with the nested for loop, however it seems to grab the attribute from every single raw material tag each time, instead of the one inside the parent line item tag

Answer (score 0):

Try using xpath, something like this:

```
for raw_material in grandchild.findall('.//Raw_Material'):
  # your code here
```

EDIT: Since grandchild refers to your LineItem elements, you might actually need something like `.//Raw_Materials/RawMaterial` as your xpath.

Comment: This is allowing me to pull the data, however it is giving me a list of the Item_Id's from each raw material tag throughout the entire document, instead of just the one inside the one line item tag. I need the attributes from the line item to correlate with the attributed from the nested raw material tag

Comment: Sorry I don't know what to tell you, it works for me: https://gist.github.com/audiodude/ad44f412779de3b802dfbcdd3a5a98f5 That prints two Raw_Material arrays, one with the first line item's elements, and the second with the second's.

Comment: Are you calling .findall on your grandchild or on root? If you call it on root, the `//` syntax will, yes, give you every one in the document.

Comment: Your test code definitely works, but my output is still incorrect: https://gist.github.com/ajrice6713/ec0f826b73158842f7ec0ea63ed82ae0

Comment: Unfortunately i need 20 reputation on stack overflow to use the chat rooms

Comment: Shoot. Well if you can figure out a way for us to chat in real time I'd be happy to help more. I don't really understand what you're trying to do (beyond "process an XML file of orders") and I don't want to wait 10 minutes every time to figure it out.

Comment: emailed from ajrice6713

Answer (score 0):

Below.

There are 6 *Raw_Material* elements in the xml doc. 4 of them are empty (zero attributes) and 2 of them has 2 attributes each. This is reflected in the 'output'

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = """<XML_Order order_Id="1" terms="Net30" ship_via="UPS">
        <Line_Items>
            <Line_Item upc="1234567" item_id="1" color="blk" qty="15">
                <Raw_Materials>
                    <Raw_Material Item_Id="H188" Vendor_Id="DI0001"/> 
                    <Raw_Material Item_Id="ST03" Vendor_Id="DI0001"/>
                </Raw_Materials>
            </Line_Item>
              <Line_Item>
                <Raw_Materials>
                    <Raw_Material/>
                    <Raw_Material/>
                </Raw_Materials>
            </Line_Item>
            <Line_Item>
                <Raw_Materials>
                    <Raw_Material/>
                    <Raw_Material/>
                </Raw_Materials>
            </Line_Item>
         </Line_Items>
    </XML_Order>"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
# getting the attributes across the xml doc
print('Raw_Materials across the XML doc:')
raw_materials_lst = [entry.attrib for entry in
                     list(root.findall(".//Raw_Material"))]
print(raw_materials_lst)

# getting the attributes per Line_Item
print('Raw_Materials per line item:')
line_items = [entry for entry in list(root.findall(".//Line_Item"))]
for idx, line_item in enumerate(line_items,1):
    print('{}) {}'.format(idx, [entry.attrib for entry in
                                list(line_item.findall(".//Raw_Material"))]))
```

output

```
Raw_Materials across the XML doc:
[{'Item_Id': 'H188', 'Vendor_Id': 'DI0001'}, {'Item_Id': 'ST03', 'Vendor_Id': 'DI0001'}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
Raw_Materials per line item:
1) [{'Item_Id': 'H188', 'Vendor_Id': 'DI0001'}, {'Item_Id': 'ST03', 'Vendor_Id': 'DI0001'}]
2) [{}, {}]
3) [{}, {}]
```

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely a workable solution. I managed to solve it last night a little differently, i will post my solution separately

Answer (score 0):

HUGE thanks to @audiodude, we worked through this for about an hour last night and managed to come up with a workable solution. Below is what he came up with, the attribute data is going into a FileMaker databse, so he set up some boolean flags to capture the item_Id in the Raw_Material tag (since some of my xml files have these tags, and some do not).

```py
for child in root:
    for grandchild in child:

        # grab any needed attribute data from the line_items element

        has_sticker = False
        has_tag = False
        for material_item in grandchild.findall('.//Raw_Material'):
            item_id = material_item.get('Item_Id')
            if item_id.startswith('H'):
                has_tag = True
                liRecord['hasTag'] = 'True'    # this is the record in my database
                fms.edit(liRecord)
            if item_id.startswith('ST'):
                has_sticker = True
                liRecord['hasSticker'] = 'True'
                fms.edit(liRecord)

        if liRecord['hasTag'] == 'False' and liRecord['hasSticker'] == 'False':
            liRecord['hasTag'] = 'True'
            fms.edit(liRecord)
```